# How to use Poisson summation formula?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $g, h \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $\langle g, h \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{g(x)} h(x) dx.$
Let $f\colon\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a nice function (so everything below make sense, e.g., if we want apply Poisson summation formula at some point), and put
$$f_n(x)= f(x-n),  n \in \mathbb Z.$$
**Question**: Can we expect:
$$ \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \langle g, f_n\rangle \langle f_n,  h \rangle  = \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{\hat{g}(\xi)} \hat{h}(\xi +k) \hat{f}(\xi) \overline{\hat{f}(\xi+k)} d\xi.$$

**My attempt**: We may apply  apply  Passeval's identity then we have $\langle g, f_n\rangle =\langle \hat{g},\hat{ f_n}\rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{\hat{g}(\xi)} \hat{f}(\xi) e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot n} d\xi .$  Thus, we may rewrite $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \langle g, f_n\rangle \langle f_n,  h \rangle$ as

$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} \left(  \int_{\mathbb R} \overline{\hat{g}(\xi)} \hat{f}(\xi) e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot n} d\xi \right) \left(  \int_{\mathbb R} \hat{h}(\xi) \overline{ \hat{f}}(\xi) e^{-2\pi i \xi \cdot n} d\xi \right)$. I'm guessing now I have to some how use [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) to get the above equation, but I do not know how...

Any suggestions and comments  are Wellcome ...

Comment: Maybe I’m just a noob . . . but could you explain some of this notation?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: Thanks. $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. Please let me know if I should explain other notations?

Comment: Acrually, that was the only notation that I *did* understand. Specifically I’m curious about $\langle g,f_n\rangle$ and $\overline{g(x)}$.

Comment: $\langle f, g \rangle$ is the inner product in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, and $\overline{g}$ is the conjugate of $g$